# Convert a result in the console into a list Python

Tags: python

I want to web scrape a list of urls from a web site and then open them one by one.
I can get the list of all urls but then try to turn into a list things get wrong.
When I print the list, intead of geting [url1, urls2...] I get something like this in the console:

```
[url1,url2,url3] dif line
[url1,url2,url3,url4] difline
[url1,url2,url3,url4,url5]
```

Find the my script bellow:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
my_url="https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/AnalizaPrzekrojowa.aspx"

driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(3)


content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
page_soup = soup(content,"html.parser")

links =[]
for link in page_soup.find_all('a', href=True):
url=link['href']
ai=str(url)
links.append(ai)
print(links)
links.append(ai)
print(links)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code a little. First you need to load and scrap main page to get all links from "href". After that just use scraped urls in a loop to get next pages.

Also there is some junk in "href" which isn't url so you have to clean it first.

I prefer requests to do GET.

```
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
```

I hope it helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def main():
    links = []
    url = "https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/AnalizaPrzekrojowa.aspx"
    web_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.content, "html.parser")
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

    for a in a_tags:
        links.append(a.get("href"))

    print(links)  # just to demonstrate that links are there

    cleaned_list = []
    for link in links:
        if "http" in link:
            cleaned_list.append(link)

    print(cleaned_list)
    return cleaned_list


def load_pages_from_links(urls):
    user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    links = urls
    downloaded_pages = {}

    if len(links) == 0:
        return "There are no links."
    else:
        for nr, link in enumerate(links):
            web_page = requests.get(link, headers=user_agent)
            downloaded_pages[nr] = web_page.content

    print(downloaded_pages)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    links = main()
    load_pages_from_links(links)
```